# user capture div as image and save to computer

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot, webcam

I have a Div on my site, I want to place a button/link (or other things of the sort) that when clicked will save the div and all its contents to the users computer, much like the printing code which is used to print divs. I'm a coding novice so all help will be apreciated.

Comment: Do you want an image captured from your div?

Comment: yeah i want the user of the site to be able to press a button and then it downloads a sort of screen shot of the div in jpg/gif/png or something

Answer (score 11):

There is a browser support limit doing this. [**HTML2Canvas**](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) can render your HTML content into a `canvas` element. Then you can use `canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` ([docs in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement#Example%3a_Getting_the_data%3a_URL_for_a_canvas)) method to export the `canvas` element to an `jpeg` or `png` image.

It's not widely supported but it's still possible.

Comment: already tried this my content wont work in a canvas element :(

Comment: You don't have to have a `canvas` in the page.

Comment: Well, this is a fresh article about what I said: http://robert.ocallahan.org/2011/11/drawing-dom-content-to-canvas.html

Answer (score 1):

Easy way

```
 var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('DIV1');
 var MyDiv3 = document.getElementById('DIV2');
 MyDiv3.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;


 html2canvas(MyDiv3, {
                    useCORS: true,
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = dataUrl;

                    }
                });
```

use a button and call ur hidden field value

```
ButtonClick1()
{
    string imgval = HiddenField1.Value;
    imgval = imgval.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
    byte[] imgData = Convert.FromBase64String(imgval);

    using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imgData)))
    {
        String path = Server.MapPath("~/imgFolder");
         image.Save(path + "\\output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // Or Png

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a text or HTML file, not an image file like a screen shot, JavaScript by itself can't initiate a "Save" dialog on a web browser, only a response from a web request to a server will do so.

To start with, you'll need a form with your button and a hidden field:

```
<div id="saveme">stuff to save</div>
<form action="saveme.aspx" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" onclick="prepsave()">
  <input type="hidden" id="savemepost">
</form>
```

And you need some Javascript to save the DIV contents to the hidden field before submittal:

```
<script>
   function prepsave() {
      document.getElementById("savemepost").value = 
        document.getElementById("saveme").innerHTML;
        return true;
   }
</script>
```

On the server, you'll need some code to accept the text and spit it back out in the form of a file attachment:

```
<script runat="server">
   Response.Clear()
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=saved.html")
   Response.Write(Request.Form("savemepost"))
</script>
```

Caveat #1: There are probably some minor bugs in there and plenty of room for improvement, this is just a proof of concept.

Caveat #2: The server-side code above is potentially insecure, as it allows any web page to control content going to the user's web browser from your domain. You'll need to add some measures to protect this from being abused.

Comment: He says he wants it to be something like a screenshot in his comment on the question.