# Parse json object of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

```
{
    "prev": [
        "demo/medium/Web081112_P002_medium.jpg",
        "demo/medium/Web081112_P003_medium.jpg"
    ],
    "curr": [
        "demo/medium/Web081112_P004_medium.jpg",
        "demo/medium/Web081112_P005_medium.jpg"
    ],
    "next": [
        "demo/medium/Web081112_P006_medium.jpg",
        "demo/medium/Web081112_P007_medium.jpg"
    ]
}
```

This is the json I got :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "scandir.php",
        data: "page=5",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(i, data){
        $('#img'+i).attr('src',data[1]);
    });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I would like to do this: `Assign <img id = "img1" src="demo/medium/Web081112_P002_medium.jpg">` and so on....

The collected data [1] only capture the values in column (3,5,7) . How to  implement this? Thanks

Comment: To be precise, how to use each to iteractive

Comment: Refer [this][1] answer. Follow this.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720815/capture-a-div-as-an-image/13720980#13720980

Comment: Could you please describe how to get the id `img1` from the keys `prev` and `0`? Notice that properties in an object are not ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your are just setting the src attribute of the second data object here...

```
$('#img'+i).attr('src',data[1]);
```

you are getting the (3,7,5) only...

you have to use  two `$.each` loops to get all the src..

try this

```
var k=1;

$.each(data, function(i, data1){
  $.each(data1, function(j, data2){
     $('#img' + k).attr('src', data2);
       k++;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your array always has two elements:

```
$.each(data, function(i, data){
    $('#img'+(2*i)).attr('src',data[0]);
    $('#img'+(2*i + 1)).attr('src',data[1]);
});
```

If you have more than two, then you'll need an inner loop:

```
var idx = 0;
$.each(data, function(i, data) {
    $.each(data[i], function(j, dataj) {
        $('#img'+(idx)).attr('src',dataj[j]);
        ++idx;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a multidimensional array, that is an object that has arrays as properties.

To loop through the arrays, you need another loop inside the loop. Use a separate counter to keep track of the image numbering.

```
var count = 1;
$.each(data, function(i, row){
  $.each(row, function(j, item){
    $('#img' + count).attr('src', item);
    count++;
  });
});
```

Note: There is no specific order to the properties in an object, so they may end up in different order depending on which browser the visitor is using.