# Saving ng-repeat items as images

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat in my html that creates around 750 divs (i am producing labels for my products), i have designed them how i would like them to look and i am happy with this, but as they are quite big the print preview doesn't look anything like my design.

I want to know if it is possible in Angular to easily iterate through each of the ng-repeat items and save them as a png?

Below is my ng-repeat :

```
<div class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="p in productcodes">
         <div class="contact-box" style="padding:0px !important;height:370px;width:650px;">
            <span ui-sref="profile">
               <div class="col-lg-3" style="padding:0px">
                  <img alt="image" class="img m-t-xs img-responsive rotateimage" style="max-width:1000% !important;width:200%" ng-src="">
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding:0px">
                  <div >
                     <h3 style="margin-top:45px;">Code:</h3>
                     <h3>Colour:</h3>
                     <h3>Item:</h3>
                     <h3>EN Cert:</h3>
                     <h3>Size GB:</h3>
                     <h3>Size SE:</h3>
                     <h3>Size EU:</h3>
                     <h3>Length:</h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3" style="padding:0px">
                  <h3 style="margin-top:45px;"><strong>{{p.pcode}}</strong></h3>
                  <strong>
                     <h3>{{p.Colour}}</h3>
                  </strong>
                  <h3>
                  {{p.shortdescription}}</h4>
                  <h3>N/A</h3>
                  <strong>
                     <h3>{{p.Size}}</h3>
                  </strong>
                  <h3>C62</h3>
                  <h3>3XL+</h3>
                  <strong>
                     <h3>{{getsize(p.SizeCode)}}</h3>
                  </strong>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding:0px">
                  <img alt="image" class="img-circle m-t-xs img-responsive"  style="margin-top:60px;width:200%;" src=".{{p.localimg}}">
               </div>
               <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you post Fiddle or Plunkr? with your code snippet?

Comment: Use ng-src for img tag

Comment: The codes quite irrelevent, i just want to save my 750 divs as 750 pngs

Comment: May this link will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025806/user-capture-div-as-image-and-save-to-computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if it is possible in Angular to easily iterate through
>   each of the ng-repeat items and save them as a png?

#### Short answer

No

### Long answer

Save as `png` where?  You can store them on server side or your comp. Its not related to Angular. For example, if you would use [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)  as image storage, you will be able to [transform image resolutions](http://cloudinary.com/cookbook/resize_an_image) for preview by changing URL:

- http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_70,h_53,c_scale/turtles.jpg:

[image]

- http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_30,h_23,c_scale/turtles.jpg

[image]

Further, its not good practice to show `750 images` at once, you gonna kill your web page. Keep in mind, after 2K of watchers the web view performance slows down.

I believe if you have fixed height of `ng-repeat` item, I would use infinite scrolling. For example take a look on [Google Material virtual Repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) approach.

#### Other solution

If your image preview is small, you can convert [image to base64](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/) and it will save you from calling 750 HTTP requests